# Fuzzy string match with dictionary in the tm package

Tags: r, dictionary, tm, fuzzy-search

I wonder if it is possible to do a fuzzy string match in the `tm` package in R with the use of `dictionary`.

For example, I have a `corpus` with 10 text files with animal names.

I want to search the `corpus` with the names mentioned in `dictionary`, but would also like to include animal names that are slightly different.

To do a complete match, I would write:

```
dictionary <- c("cat", "cats and dogs", "dog")
found_animals <- inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(docs, list(dictionary = dictionary)))
```

How can I do a fuzzy match such that `found_animals` would also include "cats", "dogs" and other approximate words. Is that possible?

Comment: You may want to look at string distance algorithms and related packages. `adist` in utils is one option. There are other good ones too like `stringdist`.

Comment: @Gopala: Thanks! I am aware of those packages. But I am not able to incorporate them into the `tm` package. Do you know a way?